# Is it possible capture the error message thrown for a program call in a RPG program?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

I am trying to make an RPG program be able to tell more specific details when a program call inside it goes wrong. The exception I want to monitor has nothing to do with bad program logic, say dividing by zero. What I want to check is if a program call has failed due to an authority issue, or program not found. Indicator at 73-74 can only tell that there is an exception but not the reason behind it. Is there any possible means to detect this in RPG, just like the MONMSG statement in a CL program?

Answer (score 3):

There are two classes of errors: Program and File.  Program errors are things like divide by zero, CALL failed, etc.  The full list is at [Program Status Codes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzasd/sc092508151.htm).  These error codes are very coarse - if you CALL PGMX and there is an authority problem, you get a 00211.  If the program is not in the library list, you get a 00211.  If the program ends abnormally (say due to an escape message) you get a 00211.  If you need to know *why* the CALL failed, you will need to interrogate the job log / program message queue.

For file errors, the [file information data structure](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzasd/sc092508135.htm) will record the error code.  File errors are things like referential constraint violation or permanent I/O error.  Again, these [file status codes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzasd/sc092508147.htm) are not very granular, and if you need to know that you had an authority failure, you'll need to find out from the job log.

One note about file errors. When you write your own error handler ([file exception error subroutine](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzasd/sc092508148.htm#fiexsub)) you need to be aware that this handler does not become active until AFTER the cycle has opened the files.  This means that if you let the cycle open the files, you cannot catch errors like "file not in library list" or "not authorised to file".  In order to catch the errors which occur at open time, you need to open the files yourself, via the OPEN op-code.  Don't forget to CLOSE them too.

Comment: I just want the top level reason to be found. Thinks like dividing by zero or level error can be regarded as one type. Authority issue is another one. Program not found is the third type.

Comment: You can certainly group errors any way you need for your app to make sense.  What I'm pointing out is that _detecting_ them is going to take two separate logical processes.  One for program errors and another one for file errors.  In old-style code, this would involve creating a *PSSR for program errors and an INFSR for file errors.  If you're comfortable enough with error handling you can make them the same SUBR.  Newer code would use the (e) opcode extender and %status, and the newest code would use MONITOR blocks.

Comment: Is it possible to use PSDS position 40~46 to in the caller program to tell the reason behind failed program call?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  But that depends entirely on how the called program terminates.  If it ends in a CEE9901 will you find that useful enough, or will you need to go backward to find the diagnostic message MCH3601 that tells you you didn't pass enough parameters?

Comment: Then is there a general message to cover all the cases? I mean if I just need to know that the called program ended abnormally, which message should I check? And is there any way to stop the break message from popping up when the called program goes wrong? I want it to be monitored, I don't want it to show off the screen and disturb the process.

Comment: If all you care about is that the CALL failed, put an indicator in the error columns or use CALL(E).  In order to stop the break message in the called program you need to monitor for messages there.

Comment: Error indicator for CALL is a bit too general. I would not have come to ask this question if it suffices.

Comment: Threads drift as ideas are suggested. You asked for one general message to cover all cases.  This is exactly what the error indicator does.  CALL(E) with %STATUS (as suggested above) will be a little more granular.  You will need to decide what degree of error recording works best for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Use [error handling operations](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzasd/sc092508771.htm#yyerror) and/or the [program exception subroutine and the program status data structure](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzasd/sc092508149.htm#progxpe) to catch and interpret specific error conditions.

Comment: Does error handling operation work in fixed format? My assumption is that this callee program will always work under normal condition, except for cases like no authority to access it, or it not found in the library list. Things like decimal error are not concerns here.

Comment: @God_of_Thunder There are fixed format and free format versions of error handling.

Comment: If I expect things like unauthorised program or program not found, which error code should I use? 211?

Comment: @God_of_Thunder You would have to test to be sure.  You can also get the CPF/MCH message number from the [PSDS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzasd/sc092508150.htm#psdsdt9) in positions 43..46 for more detailed information.